# Async/Await function returning _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null

Tags: react-native, async-await, return-value

I got this `{ _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }` returned from Async/Await function when trying to get the original size of an image. Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-size for the function usage.

Here is my code.

```
getImgSize = async (url) => {
  const {width, height} = await ImageSize.getSize(url);
  const imgSize = { width: width, height: height }

  console.log(imgSize) // result is { width: 950, height: 634 }

  return imgSize;
}

function getImage(){
  var imgSize = getImgSize("https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwNC84MzAvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrXzExMTA1NzIxNTkuanBn");

  console.log(imgSize) // result after returned { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }
}
```

I expected the result to be something like `{ width: 950, height: 634 }` but the result I mentioned been returned instead.

Comment: You're not awaiting the promise returned by getImage

Comment: What do you mean by not awaiting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try it

```
getImgSize("<Image URL>")
.then((imgSize)=>console.log(imgSize))
```

or put it in async/await

```
getImage = async () => {
  var imgSize = await getImgSize("<Image URL>");
  console.log(imgSize);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling an `async` function which means it's a promise. You gotta wait for the result.

So either use `await`

```
getImage = async () => {
  var imgSize = await getImgSize("https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwNC84MzAvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrXzExMTA1NzIxNTkuanBn");

  console.log(imgSize);
}
```

or handle it this way

```
getImage = () => {
    getImgSize('https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwNC84MzAvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrXzExMTA1NzIxNTkuanBn').then((imgSize) => {
      console.log(imgSize);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `await`  and `async` function:

```
 getImgSize = async (url) => {
      const {width, height} = await ImageSize.getSize(url);
      const imgSize = { width: width, height: height }
      console.log(imgSize) // result is { width: 950, height: 634 }
      return imgSize;
}

async function getImage(){
  var imgSize = await getImgSize("https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwNC84MzAvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrXzExMTA1NzIxNTkuanBn");
  console.log(imgSize) // result after returned { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use async with await or use the then() =>  against it lets look at that and use it where you need to wait .